# Vite PostCSS module error when building app in Svelte

Tags: svelte, vite, postcss, autoprefixer

I came across this strange error in Svelte; every time I ran `npm run dev`, this vite error would appear:

```
[vite] Internal server error: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: /Users/Documents/Personal projects): [Failed to load PostCSS config] Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: /Users/Documents/Personal projects): [Failed to load PostCSS config] Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: /Users/Documents/Personal projects): [Error] Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
```

I'm new to vite so it took me an hour of research, to figure out how to export the module, I was able to fix it by creating a `postcss.config.cjs` file and inside the file add:

```
module.exports = {
    autoprefixer: {}
}
```

I hope this helps anyone that comes across the same/similar error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create `postcss.config.cjs` file and add:

```
module.exports = {
    autoprefixer: {}
}
```

The reason why it wasn't building, is because svelte wasn't exporting the autoprefixer module

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by deleting the node_modules directory, and ran `npm i` again.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem while following a tutorial and i fixed this way.

```
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest

npx tailwindcss init -p

npm i
```

and then finally

```
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your Root folder (Root folder contains. folders like src)
2. Create a new file, name it postcss.config.js
3. Paste this into the postcss.config.js file

```js
module.exports = {
        autoprefixer: {}
    }
```

4. Save, delete npm_modules folder if its there
5. go to root folder using cd in terminal, run npm install
6. run ng serve

Answer (score 0):

Just to add this to your package.json

```
"type": "module",
```

about "scripts"

Answer (score 0):

You can also switch to entirely TypeScript

**postcss.config.ts**

```js
import tailwindConfig from './tailwind.config'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'
import tailwind from 'tailwindcss'

export default {
  plugins: [tailwind(tailwindConfig), autoprefixer],
}
```

Update **vite.config.ts** with `postcss` as a `css` config

```js
...
import postcss from './postcss.config'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
    postcss,
  },
})
```

Update **tsconfig.node.json** to `include` the config

```json
{
  ...
  "include": [
    "vite.config.ts",
    "postcss.config.ts",
    "tailwind.config.ts"
  ]
}
```

[Example From GitHub](https://github.com/emdgroup-liquid/liquid-sandbox-solid-tailwind/blob/main/postcss.config.ts)